# Tool to view response headers

Tags: http, browser, networking, http-headers

What is the best way to view the HTTP response headers from a request against a particular URL? Telnet or is there some other really good command or tool?

Comment: URLs don't have a "header" per se, requests and responses do. A request is issued against a particular resource, identified by a URL. Are you asking for a tool which shows the response headers returned from a particular request against some URL?

Comment: Thought so, but the wording wasn't quite clear.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I use the [httpfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) Firefox extension to view all HTTP requests and responses (including header and body) initiated from the web browser in the interval I specify (by pressing the start-recording and the stop-recording buttons). httpfox presents the data in a structured way in which I can quickly find the request I am interested in. It nicely complements LiveHTTPHeaders, because httpfox can view requests in the past as well.

Comment: Don't need a plugin anymore, it's built-in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Answer (score 37):

I find that [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is my weapon of choice, although there are firefox plugins as well.  Fiddler will show you all the HTTP Requests, their response status, all the headers, with different views (raw, hex, image), a timeline view, HTTPS Connects, everything.

Comment: In their site, they offer to install some addons but after virustotal test, there's a trojan hic http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=e44e811581ff40382b7a0da6244f89918b4577253e5f3287ecc77c7012533cad-1320172710

Answer (score 23):

On Linux I use:

```
wget -S [url]
```

This gets the file and shows all headers sent by the server.

On Windows one can use the same command if Cygwin is installed; either on regular command prompt, if the environment variables were properly adjusted, or through the Cygwin command window.

Comment: In the same vein: `curl -i [url]`

Comment: Will wget work on mac ?

Comment: In order to make wget work you need to install it. This is easy with brew. If you don't have that it might be better to use curl instead because it comes with Mac OS  (don't know since when it's included)

Answer (score 16):

- [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) for Firefox is pretty good. It will show the headers in real time. I prefer it to [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829).
- [Microsoft Fiddler](http://www.ieaddons.com/en/details/other/Microsoft_Fiddler/) for Internet Explorer is a web debugger that logs all HTTP traffic between your computer and the Internet. Fiddler allows you to inspect all HTTP traffic, set breakpoints, and fiddle with incoming or outgoing data
- [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a complete network protocol analyzer. It is good, but it might be overkill if HTTP headers is all that are required. It has problems if the client and server are on the same machine.

Answer (score 12):

Using a recent version of Firefox (19.0 in my case), going to menu *Tools* -> *Web Developer* -> *Web Console* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + `K` on Windows) then refreshing the page produces a log of requests.

Then clicking on one of the first GET requests, the one with the URL of the page, opens a box with information about it, including request and response headers. It works out of the box, no need for fancy-shmancy add-ons any more.

Comment: Web Console is nice but has several problem that I described in the second paragraph here: http://aegif-labo.blogspot.jp/2013/04/how-to-get-https-headers.html These are minor problems, so I agree that Web Console is the first tool to try.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [httpie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie), a very nice Python tool:
[image]

You can use the `--headers` option to view only headers:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) addon for Firefox is the easiest way I think.

Answer (score 5):

For Internet Explorer, [Fiddler](http://www.ieaddons.com/en/details/other/Microsoft_Fiddler/) will work. Or you can go all out with [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark).

Comment: FWIW, you can watch traffic from ANY web browser (or any other client which supports proxies) using Fiddler.

Comment: Note: Wireshark does not work for HTTPS

Answer (score 2):

There is a better choice (in my point of view)

It's a Firefox extension calle HTTPfox. You can not only see the header but much more information. It´s a very complete HTTP analyzer

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with the developer tools in your browser, open the network tab on the developer tools, refresh the page, then click on the headers tab. The response headers will be listed. For instance this page sends this header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Fri, 01 Mar 2013 02:00:20 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Mar 2013 01:59:20 GMT
Vary: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Fri, 01 Mar 2013 01:59:19 GMT
Content-Length: 13555
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good tool to do it for Firefox called [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829).

Answer (score 0):

[burpsuite](http://portswigger.net/burp/download.html) is a free tool, Java-based and runs on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great addon/plugin/extension called [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) from Chris Pederick.

It works with Chrome, Firefox and Opera and has mighty dev functions and also a possibility to 'View Response Headers'. You can find it within the tab 'Information'.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't looking to do it on your machine, you can use any number of online applications that do it for you.

1. [Rex Swain's HTTP viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/cgi-bin/httpview.cgi)
2. http://web-sniffer.net/: This one is a bit more flexible with regard to the app layer protocol (HTTP/S)
3. [Ask Apache](http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/http-headers-tool/): This one lets you customize your request a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an online tool [View-Http-Request-and-Response-Headers](http://spdypage.com/view-http-request-and-response-header) is great

Answer (score 0):

On Internet Explorer, inside Developer Tools (press F12), go to the Network tab and press "Start Capturing". Refresh the page, click on "Go to detailed view" and you will get a very nice overview of the request and response data.