# How to see all the details of an HTTP request

Tags: http, google-chrome, firefox

On the Wikipedia article about HTTP, this screenshot is offered as an example of all the behind-the-scenes that goes on with each HTTP request.

My question is, with Google Chrome or Firefox, is there a way to see all the HTTP headers, requests, status, type and all other specifics in the same manner as this screenshot?

[image: Wikipedia HTTP]

Comment: Have you tried Firebug in Firefox? Will that show you enough of what you need to see?

Comment: I use Firebug and it gives you pretty much all of this information - source code, individual requests, result codes, ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809302/tool-to-view-response-headers

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli Sorry it seems like the same question, I wish the asker would have mentioned HTTP in his title so I would have found it before posting this question